# What are examples of mobile user profiles?

Tags: mobile, profile

I'm working on a mobile application which needs a user profile page.

I've tried to find mobile apps with user profiles (like the one in this site), but so far all of them have been read only.  To change them you need to be on a non-mobile version.

My problem is that I can have a nice layout for reading, but that doesn't translate well into something that I can go into an edit mode for.  And something where I can edit easily looks more like a web form than a profile (although I see the overlap).

What are some mobile apps with user profiles that are both editable and have decent (i.e. non-form like) layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the simplicity of Instagram's profile pages.

I think the idea is: simple, clear, don't worry about scrolling but make sure the "submit" button is always close by. After every section there is a submit button.

My Profile Tab

[image: My Profile Tab]

Edit profile page

[image: Edit profile page]

Editing a field

[image: Editing a field]

More fields continued near the bottom

[image: More fields continued near the bottom]

Comment: +1 For a nice profile to think of in the future.  However, it isn't something that can work for us.  For various reasons we need to be able to view a profile on a single (if long) page.  From there we need to be able to edit it as close to the way that people view it as possible.

Comment: This is all on one page, you just keep scrolling. There is a submit button after every section too.

Comment: I didn't notice that.  Thanks, that helps a lot more than I thought.